# React Native and Typescript - Need an approach to create a flexible table component

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to create a table component that can display its cells flexibly. Every cells on a column displays the same cell component. The table component take an array of object as initial data and an array of column properties. Table should looks like this:

```
interface MyTableProps {
    columns: ColumnProps[];
    initialData: Array<any>; // Should array of object
    callbackTableDataChanged: (newData) => void; // being used to send modified table data back to MyTable's father components.
}

interface ColumnProps {
    label: string;
    objectPropertyName: string; // (*)
    renderCell: "cell-type-1" | "cell-type-2" | "cell-type-3" | ... // (**)
}

const MyTable: React.FC<MyTableProps> = tableProps => {
    // The table should have its own a copy of initial data, because of many reasons
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(tableProps.initialData);

    const handleDataChange = (thePropertyName: string, rowIndex: number, newValue: any) => {
        // This function changes the table data array, 
        // whenever the cell component (MyCellComp1, MyCellComp2, ...) on a column make a change of value.
        // For example: MyCellComp1 is a time picker, whenever a new timestamp selected,
        // it will send new time value through a callback, to its father component (aka MyTable).
        // Then, this func will do the changes to the corresponding "place" in the data array object of this MyTable.
    }

    const renderRows = (column: ColumnProps, rowIndex: number) => {
        switch (column.renderCell) {
            case cell-type-1: return <CellComp1 ... onDataChanged={cellData => handleDataChange(column.objectPropertyName, rowIndex, cellData)}/>
            case cell-type-2: return <CellComp2 ... onDataChanged={cellData => handleDataChange(column.objectPropertyName, rowIndex, cellData)}/>
            ...
        }
    }

    return (
        {renderColumnLabels}
        <Flatlist data={tableData} renderItem={({col, index}) => renderRows(col, index)}/>
    )
}
```

(*): "objectPropertyName" is a string that has value which is a name of one of the properties of initial object data. Forgive my awkward grammar!

(**): I use "renderCell" to tell the table what it should render at specific column. All cells on a column have the same component type.

The table should be used like this:

```
    const initialData = [
        {id: "123", name: "Tom"}, {id: "456", name: "Jerry"}, ...
    ]
    const columns: ColumnProps[] = [
        {label: "The ID", objectPropertyName: "id", renderCell: "cell-type-1"},
        {label: "The name", objectPropertyName: "name", renderCell: "cell-type-2"},
        ...
    ];

    <MyTable columns={columns} initialData={initialData} ... />

// This is how table looks like:
//                 column 1              column 2
// labels row:     The ID                The name
// row 1     :     <CellComp1 />         <CellComp2 />
// row 2     :     <CellComp1 />         <CellComp2 />
// ...
```

The problem is that with above approach, with the way I declared how cells on a column should be rendered, it limits the variety of cell component that MyTable could display. I declare 3 values for ColumnProps.rendercell, columns can display only 3 kinds of cell components.

My solution is that ColumnProps will have a new props which is a function that return a component:

```
    interface ColumnProps {
    label: string;
    objectPropertyName: string; // (*)
    renderCell: "cell-type-1" | "cell-type-2" | "cell-type-3" | ... // (**)
    renderCellComponent?: () => JSX.Element
}
```

The new "renderCellComponent" prop will replace default cell components with whatever it returns.

However, with is method, I cant change the data array of MyTable with its function "handleDataChange".

For example:

```
    const initialData = [
        {id: "123", name: "Tom"}, {id: "456", name: "Jerry"}, ...
    ]
    const columns: ColumnProps[] = [
        {label: "The ID", objectPropertyName: "id", renderCell: "cell-type-1", renderCellComponent: () => <NewCellComp1 ... />},
        {label: "The name", objectPropertyName: "name", renderCell: "cell-type-2", renderCellComponent: () => <NewCellComp2 ... />},
        ...
    ];

    <MyTable columns={columns} initialData={initialData} ... />
```

As you can see, NewCellComp1 and NewCellComp2 need to access the function "handleDataChange" of MyTable just like the way CellComp1 and CellComp2 did. In order to do that, I tried to use React.forwardRef and useImperativeHandle to MyTable:

```
const MyTable: React.FC<MyTableProps> = React.forwardRef((tableProps, ref) => {
    ...
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
        refFuncHandleDataChange(objectPropertyName: string, rowIndex, newValue) {
            handleDataChange(objectPropertyName, rowIndex, newValue);
        }
    })

    return ...
})
```

Now, MyTable should be used like this:

```
    const initialData = [
        {id: "123", name: "Tom"}, {id: "456", name: "Jerry"}, ...
    ]
    const columns: ColumnProps[] = [
        {...other props, objectPropertyName: "id", renderCellComponent: () => <NewCellComp1 onDataChanged={data => refTable.current?.refFuncHandleDataChange("id", ..., data)} />},
        {...other props, objectPropertyName: "name", renderCellComponent: () => <NewCellComp2 onDataChanged={data => refTable.current?.refFuncHandleDataChange("name", ..., data)} />},
        ...
    ];

    const refTable = useRef();

    <MyTable ref={refTable} columns={columns} initialData={initialData} ... />
```

As you can see, with this approach, I still lack the row index of the cell component that make a change of data. When cell rendering is declared inside MyTable, I can access to row index easily thanks to Flatlist, but outside MyTable does not offer that luxury, because "renderCellComponent" function of ColumnProps is a declaration for all cells on a column. This is where I'm stuck.

In conclusion, I want to create a table component that be able to display every kind of components on its cells. Also, keep its properties as "simple" as possible. You can see that I'm currently must declare only data and columns props. But my approach seems to be impossible to do that.

Can you share me an improvement for what I did or an entirely new approach for this problem. Thank you!